# Organizing my text fields in html

Tags: html, css, popup

Trying to organize my text fields the way I want.
What I want:
-username feild at the top
-first and last name underneth and next to each other
-password and confirm underneth name and next to each other

I am new to html and having trouble organizing it.  Not sure to use div, section, etc.

Also want everything to be centered and not aligned to the left and I want to add an image below all the text fields and have the add child btn underneth that.

here is the code:

```
<form>

                <label-popup for="contact">
                <span-popup>USERNAME *</span-popup>
                <input type="text" id="contact" />
                </label-popup>

                </form>

                <form>
                <div>
                <label-popup for="company">
                <span-popup>FIRST NAME *</span-popup>
                <input type="text" id="company" />
                </label-popup>

                <label-popup for="contact">
                <span-popup>LAST NAME *</span-popup>
                <input type="text" id="contact" />
                </label-popup>

                <label-popup for="contact">
                <span-popup>PASSWORD *</span-popup>
                <input type="text" id="contact" />
                </label-popup>

                <label-popup for="contact">
                <span-popup>CONFIRM PASSWORD *</span-popup>
                <input type="text" id="contact" />
                </label-popup>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: You're not talking about HTML, you're talking about CSS.  HTML by itself has no such styling, it's just content structure.  It would be a good idea to start with some tutorials on CSS.

Comment: Also what is label-popup? and span-popup are you using some library?

Comment: I am working with popup, when you click a btn you get this popup.  So i am trying to diffiereniate the main labels from the popup labels.  Is there  a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use table rather than div or section it will be easy for you.
I will provide you simple table structure for your design.

```
  <table border="0" align="center">
     <tr>
        <td>User Name <input type="text" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>First Name <input type="text" /> </td>
        <td>Last Name  <input type="text" /> </td>   
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Now add your fields in this table.

Comment: great this was a big help.  A few things.  How to I get the text (Username) to be above the text box and with this code the first and last name text and text field are directly below username.  I would like some space between each.

Comment: hi drew , if you want User Name above the text field then first remove text field from  there and  add another <tr> below  the first <tr> and in that <tr> add <td> tag inwhich you can put your text field. and for spacing between field I will suggest you cell spacing and cell padding.